# Chain two processes with in-memory layer in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis-3

I have two processes which should run after each other, first dissolve, then multipart-singlepart. Until now I have worked with file-based layers but I would like to have the output from the dissolve process as an in-memory layer which should be used in the multipart-to-singlepart process.

Currently I have each process in a single script, but would like to have them integrated into one.

This is my code so far:

Script 'Dissolve'

```
from qgis.core import *
import os
import processing

pathInput = "path/to/input.shp"
pathOutput = "path/to/dissolved.shp"

# Dissolve features based on values in attribute table field
processing.run("native:dissolve",{'INPUT':pathInput, 
                                    'FIELD':['highway', 'maxspeed', 'surface'],
                                    'OUTPUT':pathOutput}
```

Script 'Multipart to singlepart'

```
pathInput = "path/to/dissolved.shp"
pathOutput = "path/to/singlepart.shp"

processing.run("qgis:multiparttosingleparts",{'INPUT':pathInput, 
                                              'OUTPUT':pathOutput}
                                              )
```

How can I run this without creating an actual dissolve.shp-file, but instead create and use an in-memory layer, so that I can integrate both processes into one script?
I'm very sorry if this seems to be an easy task, however, I couldn't find the proper information on how to 'chain' those processes with temporary files, especially, because I don't know how to refer to the temporary dissolve file to use it in the next process.

System Windows 10

QGIS 3.28 Firenze

Comment: I think I may found an answer, referring to this source : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284064/using-memory-layer-for-processing-algorithms-in-qgis-3. So I may need to add ```dissolve_result = processing.run("native:dissolve",{'INPUT':pathInput, 
                                    'FIELD':['highway', 'maxspeed', 'surface'],
                                    'OUTPUT':'memory:'} ``` and then I'll be able to refer to the output by ```dissolve_layer = dissolve_result['OUTPUT']```

Comment: Yes that's how it is done

Comment: https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis101-chaining-processing-tools/

Answer (score 1):

The solution to chain two processes and using in-memory layer is by assigning a name to the process and defining the output of the process as 'memory:'.
In my case, the code for chaining the two process is:

```
from qgis.core import *
import os
import processing

pathInput = "path/to/input/file.shp"
pathOutput= "path/to/output/file.shp"

# Dissolve features based on values in an attribute table field
dissolve = processing.run("native:dissolve",{'INPUT':pathInput, 
                                    'FIELD':['highway', 'maxspeed', 'surface'],
                                    'OUTPUT':'memory:'})
                                    
dissolve_layer = dissolve['OUTPUT']


# Apply multipart-to-singleparts on memory-layer and save result as file
processing.run("qgis:multiparttosingleparts",{'INPUT':dissolve_layer, 
                                              'OUTPUT':pathOutput}
                                              )
```